# Typescript: Is there a way to put generic constraint on a generic class inside a method?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, monads

I have monadic data structure that look like this:

```js
export abstract class Data<A> {
  static initial<A>(): Data<A> {
    return new Initial<A>()
  }

  static failed<A>(error?: any): Data<A> {
    return new Failed<A>(error)
  }

  static loaded<A>(value: A): Data<A> {
    return new Loaded<A>(value)
  }

  static loading<A>(): Data<A> {
    return new Loading<A>()
  }

  static getData<A>(data: Loaded<A>): A {
    return data.getData()
  }

  constructor(public readonly kind: Kind) {}

  abstract map<B>(f: (a: A) => B): Data<B>

  abstract chain<B>(f: (a: A) => Data<B>): Data<B>

  abstract flatMap<B>(f: (a: A) => Data<B[]>): Data<B>[]
}
```

Where `Initial`, `Failed`, `Loaded`, and `Loading` are the four different "shapes" of my type.

Sometimes in my code I get a `Data<A>[]` that I would like to filter based on a condition on `A`. My current implementation is this:

```
  static filter<A>(data: Data<A>[], pred: (a:A) => boolean): Data<A>[] {
    return data.filter(datum => {
      if(datum.isLoaded()) {
        return pred(datum.data)
      }
      return false
    })
  }
```

Most of code uses chained methods like:

```
data.map(...).filter(...).doThis().doThat()
```

but because of the `static` sometimes the order can get messy:

```
Data.filter(data.map(...).flatMap(...), myPredicate).map(...).doThis(...) ........
```

I was wondering if there was a way to make this function non-static and use a "fluent" style of chaining the methods?

Should I extend the prototype of array for this?

Comment: Where are `isLoaded()` and the `data` property of `Data` defined?  And `Initial`, `Failed`, `Loaded`, and `Loading`?  Generally when you include code in a question it should constitute a [mcve], so that the only issues with the code are the ones you're asking about.  That sometimes means removing references to external dependencies and replacing them with stripped-down/mock/dummy versions.  Ideally someone would be able to drop your code into a standalone IDE (like [this](https://typescript-play.js.org)) and immediately get to work modifying it to make a potential solution.

Comment: I removed `isLoaded()`, `isLoading()` etc predicates to shorten the code, I thought it would be clear from their name that they just assert in what state the `Data<A>` is in. But making an online code sandbox would have been good too. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't call `Array::filter` in your `filter` function, you should just return the wrapped predicate function:

```
static loadedAnd<A>(pred: (a:A) => boolean): Data<A> => boolean {
  return datum => datum.isLoaded() && pred(datum.data);
}
```

With that you write

```
data.map(...).flatMap(...).filter(Data.loadedAnd(myPredicate)).map(...).doThis(...)
//                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: That is actually a good idea for this current specific example, I was wondering something more general, about making different versions of the same method depending on the type of `A` in `Data<A>`

Comment: @MehdiSaffar Not sure what you mean - the method already is generic over `A`? What other use cases (for "different versions") do you have?

Comment: I mean the class is defined as `Data<A>` but what if I want to have a method work only for the special case where `Data` has the shape `Data<A[]>` or `Data<Promise<A>>` for example and handle things differently.

Comment: @MehdiSaffar Then write a special method for that?

Comment: Could you show me an example like that? I precise, the method is an instance method not a static one.

Comment: For instance methods, I'm not sure how to tell TypeScript about the specialised type parameter. But for that, you better [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Comment: exactly, when it is an instance method, the type constraint is on the `this` which was the point of my question :p But maybe I wasn't able to explain my thoughts clearly

Comment: @MehdiSaffar You could try a [`this` parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#this-parameters) in the method definition